# Intellij : use ; as prefix key in a shortcut and ;; to type ;

Tags: intellij-idea

I would like to use `;` as a prefix key in a shortcut in IntelliJ (such that `;,F` triggers search) and when I press `;;` then I would like that to type `;` into the editor.

How is this possible ?

Comment: There is a vim plugin, which supposedly supports "strange" shortcuts. Maybe you can write a plugin based on that?

Comment: Hi, you wanna change some keyshorts in intellij idea?

Comment: @C-Otto I am using the vim plugin already. I think there is no functionality for leader there, need to check, that might be a solution.

Comment: I was talking about something SIMILAR to what the vim plugin does, not a configuration of the plugin itself.